# I can't seem to find my headers in the response from my express back-end in nativescript angular response

Tags: express, angular2-nativescript

I can't seem to find any headers in the response from my express back-end in nativescript angular response,i previously had `res.header` but wasn't any different.

Express back-end :

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email
    })
    .then((foundUser) => {
      if (!foundUser) res.send('Email Or Password Is Invalid');
      else {
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, foundUser.password) //compare hashed with db string
          .then((validPassword) => {
            if (!validPassword) res.send('Invalid Email Or Password').status(400);
            else {
              const token = jwt.sign({
                _userID: foundUser.userID
              }, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
              res.set({
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'x-auth-token': token
              }).send('Logged In').status(200);
            }
          });

      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      res.send('Oops something went wrong').status(500);
    });
});
```

Nativescript Http:

```
onLogin(){
    console.log(this.textScrap());
    this.registartion.Login(this.textScrap())
    .subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    },(err) => {
    console.log(err);
    },() => {
      // this.router.navigateByUrl()  Navigate to homePage when ready
    })
  }
```

Then I end up with this response but no header included

```
{
JS:   "headers": {
JS:     "normalizedNames": {},
JS:     "lazyUpdate": null,
JS:     "headers": {}
JS:   },
JS:   "status": 200,
JS:   "statusText": "Unknown Error",
JS:   "url": null,
JS:   "ok": false,
JS:   "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
JS:   "message": "Http failure during parsing for (unknown url)",
JS:   "error": {}
JS: }
```

Comment: I am facing the same error. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: i am facing same error pls give me the solution

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in NativeScript using Angular6 (and 7), and it turned out to be the Angular HttpClient rejecting empty responses with a status code of 200 instead of 204 (no content). The log showed the same message that you receive.

Even though your server code seems to send a non-empty response on successful logins ('Logged in'), you can try to add an Interceptor in your Angular appplication
to inspect the error further.

In my case I added an Interceptor which sets the body to null in case the HttpClient encounters an error and the status code indicates a successful response:

```
    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {
      HttpInterceptor,
      HttpRequest,
      HttpHandler,
      HttpResponse,
      HttpEvent,
      HttpErrorResponse
    } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Injectable()
    export class EmptyResponseBodyErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler):  Observable> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse, caught: Observable>) => {
                if (err.status >= 200 && err.status < 300) {
                    const res = new HttpResponse({
                        body: null,
                        headers: err.headers,
                        status: err.status,
                        statusText: err.statusText,
                        url: err.url
                      });
                      return of(res);
                }
                throw err;
            }
        ));
      }
    }
```

Add it to `providers` in your app.module.ts:

```
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: EmptyResponseBodyErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
```

I did not experience the same issue when running this in Chrome, Firefox or Safari, though - only in NativeScript (both Android and iOS).